# Getting a bad bind error first time can someone help me through it please

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong here getting the bad bind error?

The code is to manage stock. I have to identify when stock reaches its minimum on-hand quantity and then re-order that product.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REORDER_STOCK
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF STK_QOH,STK_MIN ON STOCK
 FOR EACH ROW

 DECLARE
 V_STK_QOH stock.STK_QOH%TYPE;
 V_STK_MIN stock.STK_MIN%TYPE;
 V_STK_REORDER STOCK.STK_REORDER%TYPE;

BEGIN 

 SELECT STK_QOH, STK_MIN, STK_REORDER
INTO V_STK_QOH, V_STK_MIN, V_STK_REORDER
FROM STOCK
WHERE STK_ID= :NEW.STK_ID;

IF:V_STK_QOH<= :STK_MIN THEN
:V_STK_REORDER := 1;
ELSE :V_STK_REORDER :=0;
END IF;

 END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
IF:V_STK_QOH<= :STK_MIN THEN
:V_STK_REORDER := 1;
ELSE :V_STK_REORDER :=0;
END IF;
```

should just be:

```
IF V_STK_QOH <= STK_MIN THEN
    V_STK_REORDER := 1;
ELSE 
    V_STK_REORDER :=0;
END IF;
```

Not sure what's required to "re-order that product", but if you're just wanting to set `STOCK.STK_REORDER` to a "1" if it reaches its minimum on hand quantity, then this is all you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER REORDER_STOCK
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF STK_QOH,STK_MIN ON STOCK
 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   IF :NEW.STK_QOH <= :NEW.STK_MIN THEN
      :NEW.STK_REORDER := 1;
   ELSE
      :NEW.STK_REORDER := 0;
   END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: The last part is correct. The OP will get ORA-04091 on the original query when they've fixed the original error as they're querying the table the trigger is based on.

Comment: @Gerrat thanks for the help, i actually had a code like the last one but i wanted to do the following i end up getting a mutating trigger. Create replace...

DECLARE V_STK_ID STOCK.STK_ID%TYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT STK_ID
INTO V_STK_ID
FROM STOCK;
  
 IF:NEW.STK_QOH<= :NEW.STK_MIN THEN
 :NEW.STK_REORDER := 1; 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RE-ORDER STOCK FOR '|| V_stk_id);
 ELSE
 :NEW.STK_REORDER :=0;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STOCK LEVEL GOOD');
 END IF;END;
/

Comment: @user1810350: As Ben mentioned, you can't select from the table you're putting the trigger on, or you'll get a mutating table error.  From what I can see you don't need to select from it.  You already have all the values you need.